# Using Custom AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource with tx:annotation-driven

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

I need to use a Custom AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource in order to intercept transaction attributes. Right now, I do this using the TransactionInterceptor and injecting this in TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor .The proxies are created using DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator as given below.

```
<bean class="org.springframework.aop.framework.autoproxy.DefaultAdvisorAutoProxyCreator"/>

<bean class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAttributeSourceAdvisor">
    <property name="transactionInterceptor" ref="txInterceptor"/>
</bean>

<bean id="txInterceptor" class="org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor">
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="txManager"/>
    <property name="transactionAttributeSource"> 
       <bean class="org.myProject.transaction.CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here, CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource extends AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource. Is there any way I can force Tx:annotation-driven to use my CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource so that I could avoid all these configurations? . I read in one of the posts that this could be done by using BeanPostProcessors but not sure how to use it for this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`<tx:annotation-driven>` doesn't do anything magic, it just registers almost the same bean definitions as you do manually (see [`AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser`](https://src.springframework.org/svn/spring-framework/trunk/org.springframework.transaction/src/main/java/org/springframework/transaction/config/AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser.java)).

So, you can either replace references to `AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource` from other beans, or replace class name property in its definition. The latter looks simplier (though more fragile with respect to changes in Spring code) and can be done by the following `BeanFactoryPostProcessor`:

```
public class AnnotationTransactionAttributeSourceReplacer implements BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
    public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory)
            throws BeansException {

        String[] names = factory.getBeanNamesForType(AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource.class);

        for (String name: names) {
            BeanDefinition bd = factory.getBeanDefinition(name);
            bd.setBeanClassName("org.myProject.transaction.CustomAnnotationTransactionAttributeSource");
        }            
    }       
}
```

Comment: Just for the record, when using the `<tx:annotation-driven />` stuff, you don't define the `AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource` bean directly but this seems to work to replace the one you get by default.  Thanks!

Comment: I experienced that control flow did not return from `getBeanNamesForType`. Using `getBeanNamesForType` with additional parameters false and false solved the issue.