# how to extend method afterPropertiesSet()

Tags: java, spring, quartz-scheduler

In my spring configuration I define bean

```
bean id="com.companyName.schedulerBean"
    class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean"
```

I want to extend logic of method `SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()`. 
If there any way to do it?

For example now `SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()` does logic:

1. initialize schedulerFactory and Scheduler
2. registerJobDetails

I want such method logic:

1. initialize schedulerFactory and Scheduler
2. remove existing jobs
3. registerJobDetails

Thanks in advance.

p.s. Sorry for my english.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't extend methods in the way you want. Provided that methods are not private or final you can override them in subclasses and call the super class method using `super`:

```
 public void someMethod() {
   //you can add code here
   super.someMethod();
   //or here
 }
```

In that case you can add code *before* or *after* the call to `super.someMethod()`. You can't however, add code in between.

Thus with this approach you can achieve the following:

```
remove existing jibs //jobs instead of jibs? In that case this position might not make much sense
initialize schedulerFactory and Scheduler    
registerJobDetails
```

or this

```
initialize schedulerFactory and Scheduler    
registerJobDetails
remove existing jibs
```

If the method you want to add code in between calls some other methods internally you could try to override one of those (they might even be designed for this). Alternatively you could use AOP and create a point cut for a method that is called internally.

In case there are no internally called methods to override the only other solution would be to copy the content of `SchedulerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet()` and add your code in between.

However, that's not advisable so I'd prefer to either add the code before or after the call to `super`(if possible) or override an internally called method.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating your own CustomSchedulerFactoryBean extending SchedulerFactoryBean . Create a BeanFactoryPostProcessor to replace SchedulerFactoryBean references with your CustomSchedulerFactoryBean  class as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316747/using-custom-annotationtransactionattributesource-with-txannotation-driven)