# How to override ResourceHttpRequestHandler to implement a customized resource handler?

Tags: model-view-controller, spring-mvc, resources, web-config, overriding

When I use spring mvc, I use `<mvc:resources />` to map the location of the static resources to handler, and now I want to add some new functions to handler resource, is there anyone who can tell me how to override the ResourceHttpRequestHandler?

(Based on the following doc, the `<mvc:resources />` use ResourceHttpRequestHandler to handle resources.)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tried this but you could try extending the ResourceHttpRequestHandler and use a BeanFactoryPostProcessor to replace ResourceHttpRequestHandler class with your custom class . A similar solution is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316747/using-custom-annotationtransactionattributesource-with-txannotation-driven)

Sample...

```
public class ResourceHttpRequestHandlerReplacer implements   BeanFactoryPostProcessor {
public void postProcessBeanFactory(ConfigurableListableBeanFactory factory)
        throws BeansException {

    String[] names = factory.getBeanNamesForType(ResourceHttpRequestHandler.class);

    for (String name: names) {
        BeanDefinition bd = factory.getBeanDefinition(name);
        bd.setBeanClassName("org.myProject.CustomResourceHttpRequestHandler");
    }            
  }       
}
```