# Activate @Transactional only for predefined packages using Java Config

Tags: java, spring, spring-transactions

`@EnableTransactionManagement` will scann all Spring Beans for `@Transactional` in order to provide transaction management.

Is it possible to provide list of the packages, that will be scanned?

For example: I would like to have support for `@Transactional` in package `a.b.c` but I would like to ignore classes marked with `@Transactional` in package `x.y.z`.

The reason for such wird requirement is 3-party lib. It has `@Transactional(readonly=false)` on almost every class, but it does only in-memory operations. Every time when I call this API spring obtains DB connection, and I really need to avoid that. I would like to exclude this whole lib from transaction management. I also cannot create separate spring context for this lib.

Comment: Can't you just add exclude filters in your own package scan to ignore the 3-party lib classes? See http://www.concretepage.com/spring/spring-component-scan-include-and-exclude-filter-example-using-javaconfig-and-xml-with-annotation-assignable-aspect-and-regex-filter-types

Comment: no, because those are spring beans as well

Comment: Looks like you need own AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource where you can provide TransactionAnnotationParser to skip the classes but I don't know how to add the source properly. See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8316747/using-custom-annotationtransactionattributesource-with-txannotation-driven

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can define your custom transaction manager in the configuration file: 
Example:

```
 <tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="txManagerRest" proxy-target-class="true"/>

<bean id="txManagerRest" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSourceRest"/>
</bean>
```

Then you can set in the classes you want this custom transaction manager like:

```
@Transactional("txName")
```

or

```
@Transactional(value = "txName")
```

In this way you would be using transactional where you want.
Moreover, you can now have as many transaction managers as you want and use it accordingly wherever you need.

Comment: Methods marked with @Transacitonal in 3-party lib would still require transaction manager, since at least one is active. An I cannot change this code.